# Change event not firing for checkbox in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension where I am dynamically creating the checkbox. Now in document ready I have placed the code to handle the "checked" change event of checkbox but the code is not working as expected because am not getting any alerts when i click it.

**Creating dynamic checkbox:**

```
function createExtensionUI(extensionListArray){
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    var extensionLength = extensionListArray.length;

    for(var i=0; i<extensionLength; i++){

        var extensionObject = extensionListArray[i];
        if(extensionObject.type == "extension"){        
            var checkbox = '<label><input type="checkbox" class= "extensionbox" id= ' + extensionObject.id  + '/>'+extensionObject.shortName+'</label>';
            $('#extensionList').append(checkbox);
            bkg.console.log(checkbox);
        }
    }

}
```

**dynamic checkbox html code sample:**

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" class= "extensionbox" id= "llegcghmokaemodgdddnchiijfdbfnlg"/>Coremetrics Bar for Chrome</label>
```

**Code for change event:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    chrome.management.getAll(getExtensionList);

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });


});
```

Am not getting any "hello" alert. My UI for extension is coming properly.

I have tried the following but they also didn't worked:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change
$(".extensionbox").change
```

I am using jquery version `1.11.1`

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: where is the script ? is it in the same file as html?

Comment: @AlexArt. No error in console.

Comment: @WisdmLabs : I have included the `js` file in my html file as `<script src="dropdown.js"></script>`

Comment: This is not valid HTML; escape the id with quotation marks.

Comment: @RanRag `...  id="' + extensionObject.id  + '"/>'`

Comment: I guess what happens is your callbacks execute out of order. Add code where you call `createExtensionUI`

Comment: @Xan I tried that as well but still same. See updated html in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60616/discussion-between-xan-and-ranrag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in asynchronous execution. *Hard to say for sure without your `getExtensionList` code though.*

You apparently create your elements from `getExtensionList`, which gets executed **after** the rest of `$(document).ready`, so your listeners do not attach because DOM elements don't exist yet.

To fix, move the code that attaches listeners to the end of `createExtensionUI`, it belongs there logically anyway.